# How to add subfolders delete functionality

Tags: php, subdirectory

This is the script it deletes all the files from a directory but it is not  deleting the empty subfolders and subfolders with files in it.

```
<?Php
$dir='directory name here'; // directory name 
$ar=scandir($dir); 
$box=$_POST['box'];  // Receive the file list from form

// Looping through the list of selected files ///
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($box)) {
$path=$dir  ."/".$val;
if(unlink($path)) echo "Deleted file ";
echo "$val,";
}
echo "<hr>";

/// displaying the file names with checkbox and form ////
echo "<form method=post name='f1' action=''>";
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($ar)) {
if(strlen($val)>3){
echo "<input class=roundedOne id=roundedOne type=checkbox name=box[] value='$val'>$val<br>";
}
}
echo "<input class=button1 type=submit value='Delete'></form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will delete subfolders and its files:

```
function removeDir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object !== '.' && $object !== '..') {
                if (filetype($dir.'/'.$object) === "dir") {
                    removeDir($dir . '/' . $object);
                }
                else {
                    unlink($dir.'/'.$object);
                }
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        unlink($dir);
    }
}
```

You can use it by executing `removeDir($dir);`

Comment: where should i put the directory path?

Comment: You can use it by executing `removeDir($dir);`

Comment: thanks it worked now one thing more the empty subfolders are not removing so what should be the solution for those